# Subset dataframe in R, dplyr filter row values of column A not NA in row of column B

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, subset

I have a dataset consisting of a time series study.  Since some participants didn't show up for certain days, they have NA values for rest of the data frame, but certain study days were crucial, so I am trying to subset my data to participants not missing these crucial days.  My dataset  is actually very large but here's the general structure:

```
fakedat <- data.frame(ID = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
                          "D", "D", "D", "D", "E", "E", "E", "E", "F", "F", "F", "F"),
                           StudyDay = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 
                                        1, 2, 3, 4),
                           Ab = c(10, NA, 15, 10, 10, 20, 10, NA, 10, 10, NA, 30, NA, NA, 15, NA, 10, 20,
                                  10, 30, NA, 10, NA, 20))
```

Now let's say it was crucial they show up at day 2 and 4, I tried subsetting using dplyr filtering like this:

```
fakedat2 <- fakedat %>%
  dplyr::group_by(ID) %>%
  dplyr::filter(StudyDay %in% c(2, 4) & !is.na(Ab)) %>%
  dplyr:: ungroup()
```

EDIT: But the output of this dataset is only the list if IDs that have a 2 or 4 that's not an NA value.  I need to find (in my real data) subjects who have NA Ab values at 4 specific Study Days.
The answer I accepted below works but still curious about performing conditional filtering?   Like in SAS you could code "IF Ab!=NA at (StudyDay=2 AND StudyDay=4) THEN ID ....or something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this will achieve your goal. If all participants have all `StudyDay` timepoints, and you just want to see if not missing in days 2 or 4, you can just check the `Ab` values at those time points in your `filter`. In this case, an `ID` will be omitted if is `NA` in both days 2 and 4 (in this example, "D").

Alternatively, if you want to require that both values are available for days 2 and 4, you can use `&` (AND) instead of `|` (OR).

```
library(dplyr)

fakedat %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  filter(!is.na(Ab[StudyDay == 2]) | !is.na(Ab[StudyDay == 4]))
```

If you have multiple days to check are not missing, you can use `all` and check values for `NA` where the `StudyDay` is `%in%` a vector of required days as follows:

```
required_vals <- c(2, 4)

fakedat %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  filter(all(!is.na(Ab[StudyDay %in% required_vals])))
```

**Output**

```
   ID    StudyDay    Ab
   <chr>    <dbl> <dbl>
 1 A            1    10
 2 A            2    NA
 3 A            3    15
 4 A            4    10
 5 B            1    10
 6 B            2    20
 7 B            3    10
 8 B            4    NA
 9 C            1    10
10 C            2    10
11 C            3    NA
12 C            4    30
13 E            1    10
14 E            2    20
15 E            3    10
16 E            4    30
17 F            1    NA
18 F            2    10
19 F            3    NA
20 F            4    20
```

Comment: Not only are you correct but because of your answer I realized my code was wrong.  It is providing me with a dataframe of all the ID where a 2 isn't NA or a 4 isn''t.  You're answer gives me the dataframe I needed in the sample data, but not my actual data- I was still having some crucial dates with NA values.  I changed "|" to "&" `filter(!is.na(Ab[StudyDay == 2]) | !is.na(Ab[StudyDay == 4])' and this seems to be what I need now.

Comment: @jrokh I was wondering about that...and first time I posted the answer had & (AND) instead of | (OR). But I was trying to match your output as intended. It gets at the question - do both 2 & 4 need to be present, or just one of the two. We can edit the answer or keep it as is, with explanation.

Comment: Gotcha- I edited my question so people can see- I could not find a good answer for this anywhere).  Yes, it would be 2 AND 4, so I'm guessing my code did 2 OR 4 correct?  I only have 4 dates now but I may end up with a lot more.  Is there a shorthand or do would I have to write out StudyDay== x?

Comment: @jrokh See edited answer. You can create a vector of "required days", then use `all` in your `filter`. This checks values of `Ab` to make sure not `NA` where the `StudyDay` is included in the required vector.

Answer (score 1):

In `base R`, we can do

```
subset(fakedat, ID %in% ID[StudyDay %in% c(2, 4) & !is.na(Ab)])
```

-output

```
#    ID StudyDay Ab
#1   A        1 10
#2   A        2 NA
#3   A        3 15
#4   A        4 10
#5   B        1 10
#6   B        2 20
#7   B        3 10
#8   B        4 NA
#9   C        1 10
#10  C        2 10
#11  C        3 NA
#12  C        4 30
#17  E        1 10
#18  E        2 20
#19  E        3 10
#20  E        4 30
#21  F        1 NA
#22  F        2 10
#23  F        3 NA
#24  F        4 20
```

---

Or a similar option in `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
fakedat %>%
     filter(ID %in% ID[StudyDay %in% c(2, 4) & !is.na(Ab)])
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, I had made an error in my initial question which I fixed- I didn't realize `[StudyDay %in% c(2, 4) & !is.na(Ab)])` was returning subjects as long as they didn't have an NA at both 2 and 4, not in at least 1.  His solution, in addition to not having to write out all the days (there could be a few) was to making a vector of required, both worked and is the same structure as yours.  Am I allowed to check this is a solution, because it was, just to the question I asked wrong? Thanks for your help!